# Convert current time to nearest half hour

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have a list of times displayed as radio buttons. I would like to use JavaScript to select the one closest to the users current time.  I'm already using jquery on my site (if that matters). Also I have another set of radio buttons that I'd like to default to select to +3 hours from the "Earliest Acceptable Time".

```
<label for="select-choice-etime">Earliest acceptable time:</label>
<select name="select-choice-etime" id="select-choice-etime">
    <option value="12:00 AM">12:00 AM</option>
    <option value="12:30 AM">12:30 AM</option>
    <option value="1:00 AM">1:00 AM</option>
    <option value="1:30 AM">1:30 AM</option>
    <option value="2:00 AM">2:00 AM</option>
    <option value="2:30 AM">2:30 AM</option>
    <option value="3:00 AM">3:00 AM</option>
    <option value="3:30 AM">3:30 AM</option>
    <option value="4:00 AM">4:00 AM</option>
    <option value="4:30 AM">4:30 AM</option>
    <option value="5:00 AM">5:00 AM</option>
    <option value="5:30 AM">5:30 AM</option>
    <option value="6:00 AM">6:00 AM</option>
    <option value="6:30 AM">6:30 AM</option>
    <option value="7:00 AM">7:00 AM</option>
    <option value="7:30 AM">7:30 AM</option>
    <option value="8:00 AM">8:00 AM</option>
    <option value="8:30 AM">8:30 AM</option>
    <option value="9:00 AM">9:00 AM</option>
    <option value="9:30 AM">9:30 AM</option>
    <option value="10:00 AM">10:00 AM</option>
    <option value="10:30 AM">10:30 AM</option>
    <option value="11:00 AM">11:00 AM</option>
    <option value="11:30 AM">11:30 AM</option>
    <option value="12:00 PM">12:00 PM</option>
    <option value="12:30 PM">12:30 PM</option>
    <option value="1:00 PM">1:00 PM</option>
    <option value="1:30 PM">1:30 PM</option>
    <option value="2:00 PM">2:00 PM</option>
    <option value="2:30 PM">2:30 PM</option>
    <option value="3:00 PM">3:00 PM</option>
    <option value="3:30 PM">3:30 PM</option>
    <option value="4:00 PM">4:00 PM</option>
    <option value="4:30 PM">4:30 PM</option>
    <option value="5:00 PM">5:00 PM</option>
    <option value="5:30 PM">5:30 PM</option>
    <option value="6:00 PM">6:00 PM</option>
    <option value="6:30 PM">6:30 PM</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="7:00 PM">7:00 PM</option>
    <option value="7:30 PM">7:30 PM</option>
    <option value="8:00 PM">8:00 PM</option>
    <option value="8:30 PM">8:30 PM</option>
    <option value="9:00 PM">9:00 PM</option>
    <option value="9:30 PM">9:30 PM</option>
    <option value="10:00 PM">10:00 PM</option>
    <option value="10:30 PM">10:30 PM</option>
    <option value="11:00 PM">11:00 PM</option>
    <option value="11:30 PM">11:30 PM</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I honestly had no clue where to get started. :/ elclanrs has given me some good ideas though.

Comment: If it is `6:45 PM` you want to choose `6:30 PM` or `7:00 PM`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a function to convert the current time to the nearest half hour in the form used in your options (e.g nearest "10:30 PM" type time) and then a way to use that time to select the proper option.

```
function getNearestHalfHourTimeString() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var ampm = "AM";
    if (minutes < 15) {
        minutes = "00";
    } else if (minutes < 45){
        minutes = "30";
    } else {
        minutes = "00";
        ++hour;
    }
    if (hour > 23) {
        hour = 12;
    } else if (hour > 12) {
        hour = hour - 12;
        ampm = "PM";
    } else if (hour == 12) {
        ampm = "PM";
    } else if (hour == 0) {
        hour = 12;
    }

    return(hour + ":" + minutes + " " + ampm);
}
```

You can select the desired option with this:

```
// remove any previous selection
$('#select-choice-etime option').removeAttr('selected');

// select the one that matches the current time
$('#select-choice-etime option[value="' + getNearestHalfHourTimeString() + '"]').attr('selected', 'selected');​
```

You can see it work here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/Zz7pW/

Comment: Getting an unexpected token error but I know this solution works.  Something is up with my jquery mobile code probably.  Do you happen to know if they changed the option selected method in jqm or recent jquery updates?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming you want to round the minutes *up* to the nearest 00/30/60 you can use the ceiling function:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setMinutes(Math.ceil(now.getMinutes() / 30) * 30);

// Test cases:
// Math.ceil( 0 / 30) * 30 =  0
// Math.ceil( 1 / 30) * 30 = 30
// Math.ceil(30 / 30) * 30 = 30
// Math.ceil(31 / 30) * 30 = 60
// Math.ceil(59 / 30) * 30 = 60
//
// Note that setMinutes(60) increments the hour and sets the minute equal to zero

var h12h = now.getHours();
var m12h = now.getMinutes();
var ampm;
if (h12h >= 0 && h12h < 12) {
    if (h12h === 0) {
        h12h = 12; // 0 becomes 12
    }
    ampm = "AM";
}
else {
    if (h12h > 12) {
        h12h -= 12; // 13-23 becomes 1-11
    }
    ampm = "PM";
}
var timeString = h12h + ":" + ("00" + m12h).slice(-2) + " " + ampm;
$("#select-choice-etime").val(timeString);
```

Note: replace ceil with round to map minutes 00...14 to 00, 15...44 to 30 and 44...59 to 60.

**[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/LVCGJ/)**

Comment: first two lines are what I searched for

Comment: `var now = new Date();
now.setMinutes(Math.ceil(now.getMinutes() / 30) * 30);`
works great on angular too. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There! This will get you started:

```js
var time = new Date(),
  hours = time.getHours(),
  minutes = (time.getMinutes().length < 2) ? time.getMinutes() : '0' + time.getMinutes();
ampm = 'AM';

if (hours.match(/[13-23]/)) {
  ampm = 'PM';
}

// You have to convert 13 to 1, 14 to 2 etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

This one is based on the GMT time `tz=GM`in the query string:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $.getJSON("http://json-time.appspot.com/time.json?tz=GMT&callback=?", function(data) {
        var GMT3 = data.hour; // data.hour+3 (if you want to use GMT+3
        if (data.minute < 15) {
            alert("Current Time is: " + GMT3 + " Selected  is " + GMT3 + ":00");
        }
        else if (data.minute < 45) {
            alert("Current Time is: " + GMT3 + " Selected is" + GMT3 + ":30");
        }
        else {
            alert("Current Time is: " + GMT3 + " Selected is" + GMT3 + 1 + ":00");
        }
    })
});​
```

The getJSON method returns:

```
{
  "tz": "GMT", 
  "hour": 8, 
  "datetime": "Thu, 01 Mar 2012 08:12:25 +0000", 
  "second": 25, 
  "error": false, 
  "minute": 12
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For start you can inspect this code.

```
var now = new Date();
var hour = now.getHours();
var min = now.getMinutes();
var ext = hour > 11 ? 'PM' : 'AM';

var tempRes = $("<select>");
// first we select all PM or AM and append to temp element
$("#select-choice-etime > option[value$='" + ext + "']").appendTo(tempRes);

// and then we select current hour elements within PM or AM
var result = tempRes.find("option[value^='" + hour + "']");

// finally we have two elements in result variable
// for example if hour is 10:12 PM
// result has two items which are 10:00 PM and 10:30 PM
//
// i think you can solve from there
```